Crystal Reports Winforms Viewer Component for Net9
Does anyone know if crystal reports by sap.com will have a viewer for net9, I believe at the moment it only supports the .net framework up to 4.8.
I wondered if the winforms viewer would support net7,8,9 etc?
Closest i've found is: https://github.com/gerardo-lijs/CrystalReportsRunner
(I know, no-one uses crystal reports any more)

Sorry, so far the answer is 'no'.
The Crystal runtime has dependencies on the older COM architecture.
SAP has consistently indicated this means they don't plan to move beyond .NET "classic".
Technically, I actually think they have a way to move forward. But they don't seem interested.
